# ROS2 rviz2 dockable panel plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, ros, ros2

I am trying implement rviz2 plugin in ROS2. I have referred [user guide](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/ros2/docs/plugin_development.md) from the rviz for the development. Currently there no tutorial available to develop rviz dockable panel in ROS2. Therefore I have referred [MoveIt2](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2) and [Navigation 2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2) package for their rviz plugin implementation in ROS2. Here is my code.

`demo_widget.h`:

```
#ifndef DEMO_WIDGET_H
#define DEMO_WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include "ui_pointcloud_controller.h"

#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <std_msgs/msg/string.hpp>
#endif

namespace Ui {
    class DemoWidgetUI;
}

namespace prc_demo_panel
{
    class DemoWidget : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            DemoWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
            ~DemoWidget() override;
        public Q_SLOTS:            
        private Q_SLOTS:
        protected:
            std::unique_ptr<Ui::DemoWidgetUI> ui_;
        
        private:
            rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr _node;
            rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr _publisher;
    };
}
```

`demo_widget.cpp`:

```
#include <prc_demo_panel/demo_widget.h>


namespace prc_demo_panel
{
    DemoWidget::DemoWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent), ui_(new Ui::DemoWidgetUI)
    {
        ui_->setupUi(this);

        connect(ui_->pushButton_1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DemoWidget::buttonOne);
        connect(ui_->pushButton_2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DemoWidget::buttonTwo);

        auto options = rclcpp::NodeOptions().arguments({"--ros-args --remap __node:=dialog_action_client"});
        _node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("_", options);

        _publisher = _node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("gui_control", 10);
    }

}
```

`demo_panel.h`:

```
#ifndef DEMO_PANEL_H
#define DEMO_PANEL_H

#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <rviz_common/panel.hpp>
#include <prc_demo_panel/demo_widget.h>

namespace prc_demo_panel
{
    class Demo_widget;

    class DemoPanel : public rviz_common::Panel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            explicit DemoPanel(QWidget * parent = 0);
            virtual ~DemoPanel();

            void onInitialize() override;
            void save(rviz_common::Config config) const override;
            void load(const rviz_common::Config &conf) override;
        
        
        private:
            DemoWidget *_widget;
        
    };
}

#endif // RVIZ_PANEL_H
```

`demo_panel.cpp`:

```
#include "prc_demo_panel/demo_panel.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <rviz_common/display_context.hpp>

namespace prc_demo_panel
{
    DemoPanel::DemoPanel(QWidget * parent) : Panel(parent)
    {
        _widget = new DemoWidget(parent);
        QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(_widget);
        layout->setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        setLayout(layout);
    }

    void DemoPanel::save(rviz_common::Config config) const
    {
        Panel::save(config);
    }

    void DemoPanel::load(const rviz_common::Config &conf)
    {
        Panel::load(conf);
    }

    void DemoPanel::onInitialize()
    {
        auto node = getDisplayContext()->getRosNodeAbstraction().lock()->get_raw_node();
    }
}

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(prc_demo_panel::DemoPanel, rviz_common::Panel)
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(prc_demo_panel)
.
.
.

# find dependencies

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Test Concurrent)

set (THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS
  rclcpp  
  class_loader
  pluginlib
  Qt5
  rviz2
  rviz_common
  rviz_default_plugins
  rviz_rendering
  rviz_ogre_vendor
)

include_directories(
  include
)


# I prefer the Qt signals and slots to avoid defining "emit", "slots",
# etc because they can conflict with boost signals, so define QT_NO_KEYWORDS here
# e.g. http://muddyazian.blogspot.de/2012/04/getting-qt-app-working-with-boost-using.html
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
#set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
#add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

# Define source file
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS
  src/demo_panel.cpp
  src/demo_widget.cpp
  #src/plugin_init.cpp
)

# Define header file
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HDRS
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/demo_panel.h
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/demo_widget.h
)

# Define ui file
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_UIS
  resource/pointcloud_controller.ui
)

message(STATUS "Generate header for ui with rviz2_QT_VERSION: ${rviz2_QT_VERSION}")
qt5_wrap_ui(${PROJECT_NAME}_UIS_H ${${PROJECT_NAME}_UIS})
foreach(header "${${PROJECT_NAME}_HDRS}")
  qt5_wrap_cpp(${PROJECT_NAME}_MOCS ${header})
endforeach()


## Add library is needed in order to generate the header file from ui file.
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS}
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_UIS_H}
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MOCS}
)
ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} rviz_common::rviz_common)
# target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
#   $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
#   $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
# )
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "PLUGINLIB__DISABLE_BOOST_FUNCTIONS")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "RVIZ_DEFAULT_PLUGINS_BUILDING_LIBRARY")


pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(rviz_common demo_plugin.xml)

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
ament_export_targets(${PROJECT_NAME} HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
ament_export_dependencies(${THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS})

ament_package()
```

`package.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>prc_demo_panel</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Point Cloud Resolution Control</description>
  <maintainer email="vishnu.pbhat93@gmail.com">vishnu</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>qtbase5-dev</build_depend>
  
  <exec_depend>libqt5-core</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-gui</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-opengl</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>libqt5-widgets</exec_depend>
  
</package>
```

`demo_plugin.xml`:

```
<library path="/libprc_demo_panel" >
  <class 
    name="prc_demo_panel/Demo Panel"
    type="prc_demo_panel::DemoPanel" 
    base_class_type="rviz_common::Panel" 
  >
    <description>
      Point Cloud Resolution Control
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

This package can compile `colcon build --symlink-install` without any errors and rviz2 is able recognize the plugin. However when I try to add the plugin in rviz2 I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] [1634722985.299621064] [rviz2]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'prc_demo_panel/Demo Panel' failed to load. 
Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin prc_demo_panel/Demo Panel. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
```

I am not able to determine what is a mistake that I am doing. I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Please could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are having. This will help users to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am sure you have figured out the answer to this, just to make sure that others are able to find the answer easily here is what is causing the issue.

The causing of this error is usually the wrong library path. Library path in `demo_plugin.xml` should be changed to the ros package name of your ros package ( If you build the whole package as a library. ), such as `<library path="prc_demo_panel" >`. If your ros package has lots of sublibraries, you should change library name to the name of library which your panel lacated.